# Primary Key for X509 Certificate KVStore

Tags: x509certificate, x509

I'm going to store root and intermediate certificates (from different CA) into some KVStore.

The problem: I have a leaf certificate (only) that I want to validate based on certificates from my store.  The leaf certificate has `Authority Key Identifier` == `Subject Key Identifier` of a parent that already must be present in the KVStore.

Question: What should I use as a Key in KVStore?

1.`Subject Key Identifier`:`certificate` or it can be the same within single CA or different CAs. what about renewal or keys rotation?

2.`Subject Key Identifier + Subject DN`: `certificate` - not sure that there is a difference with first.

3.`Subject Key Identifier`: list[`certificate`]

4.`Serial Number + Issuer` is unique but leaf certificate doesn't contain this date about parent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Subject Key Identifier` is a hash value over the certified public key. Thus, depending on the CA's key rotation policy this may or may not change during certificate renewal. It is therefore not guaranteed that the mapping `SKI:certificate` is unique.

A combined index as in option 2 does not change that.

Option 4 should be ruled out since the child certificate does not know the issuer and serial number of its parent.

Option 3 may be a valid solution in most cases, however, the `Authority Key Identifier` extension is not mandatory for X.509 certificates. So you may have to deal with leaf certificates without the AKI extension.

This typically leads to option 5: `Subject DN: list[certificate]`. Preferably with a sorted list that has the most likely CA certificate on top.

However, if your application only deals with leaf certificates with an AKI extension and all CA certificates require a key rotation during renewal option 1 may be a tick more performant. In that case I'd also keep an entry `Subject DN: list[Subject Key Identifier]`.